# Ajax post request for float value error

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I am to show float value but i can't. I already tried JSON.stringify() but it wont work. Please help me.

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/GetItemsByFilter",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                CategoryId: '',
                SubCategoryId: '',
                SubSubCategoryId: $("#sub_sub_category_id").val(),
                MinPrice: $("#min_price").val(),
                MaxPrice: $("#max_price").val(),
                BrandId: $("#brand").val(),
                OrderBy: $("#price_direction").val(),
                PageNumber: currentPage,
                PageSize: 18
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert("There is something wrong!!!");
            },
```

From Controller:

```
        ViewBag.MinPrice = Convert.ToDouble( ItemList.Min(m => m.PriceAfterDiscount));
        ViewBag.MaxPrice = Convert.ToDouble(ItemList.Max(m => m.PriceAfterDiscount));
```

GetItemsByFilter:

```
            double MinPrice = Convert.ToDouble(Request["MinPrice"]);
            double MaxPrice = Convert.ToDouble(Request["MaxPrice"]);
            double ActualMaxPrice = Convert.ToDouble(Request["ActualMaxPrice"]);
            string SubSubCategoryId = Request["SubSubCategoryId"];
            string CategoryId = Request["CategoryId"];
            string SubCategoryId = Request["SubCategoryId"];
            string BrandId = Request["BrandId"];
            string OrderByS = Request["OrderBy"];
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking. Can you add more detail to your question?

Comment: How can i show decimal value from ajax? my max and min price is in decimal value

Comment: What is the field with float value?, Can you post `/Home/GetItemsByFilter` code (only header is neccesary)?

Comment: I edit the question and add GetItemsByFilter method, Will u please help me..

Comment: Where is the success method?? Is it calling your controller action method??

Comment: Yeah... my main problem is when the max price and min price is int it works perfect but when it comes in decimal , its not working